# Finite product of homotopy classes.

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification, homotopy-theory

I've been trying to proof this theorem. I think I can prove it by using mathematical induction but I'm not sure about my attempt. Any hints on how I can tackle this problem will be greatly appreciated.

Let $f_{1},f_{2},\cdot\cdot\cdot f_{n}$ be paths on $X$ such that  $f_{i}(1)=f_{i+1}(0)$, for $i=1, 2, \cdot\cdot\cdot, n-1$. Then

$[f_{1}]\ast[f_{2}]\ast \cdot\cdot\cdot\ast[f_{n}]=[(((f_{1}\ast f_{2})\ast f_{3})\ast\cdot\cdot\cdot)\ast f_{n}].$

Proof. This proof is by induction on $n$.

If $n=2$, the problem comes down to proving that $[f_{1}]\ast[f_{2}]=[f_{1}\ast f_{2}]$ which follows inmediatly from the definition of $\ast$.

Suppose that the result holds $n=k$, we have

\begin{align*} 
    [f_{1}]\ast[f_{2}]\ast\cdot\cdot\cdot\ast[f_{k}]=[(((f_{1}\ast f_{2})\ast f_{3})\ast\cdot\cdot\cdot)\ast f_{k}].
\end{align*}

Now let's prove that the results holds for $n=k+1$.

\begin{align*} 
       [f_{1}]\ast[f_{2}]\ast\cdot\cdot\cdot\ast[f_{k+1}]&=([f_{1}]\ast[f_{2}]\ast\cdot\cdot\cdot\ast[f_{k}])\ast[f_{k+1}] \\
       &=[(((f_{1}\ast f_{2})\ast f_{3})\ast\cdot\cdot\cdot)\ast f_{k}]\ast[f_{k+1}] \\    
      &=[((((f_{1}\ast f_{2})\ast f_{3})\ast\cdot\cdot\cdot)\ast f_{k})\ast f_{k+1}]\\
       &=[(((f_{1}\ast f_{2})\ast f_{3})\ast\cdot\cdot\cdot)\ast f_{k+1}].
\end{align*}

Comment: Assuming you have already proved the associative law for the $*$ operator on path homotopy classes, this looks just fine. But if you haven't done that yet, then the expression $[f_1]*[f_2]*...*[f_n]$ is fishy --- $n$-ary expressions are not ordinarily allowed *until* the associative law has been proved.  Perhaps, though, you are using a definition of $[f_1]*[f_2]*...*[f_n]$ in which the parentheses are inserted in a very explicit manner? If so, you should explain that carefully. If not, then your fourth-from-the-last equals sign is suspicious.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply. I already proved the associative law for the $\ast$. This theorem is intended to generalize the associative law for the $\ast$ operator.

Comment: It indicates that it does not matter the order in which we operate the path homotopy classes when calculating the product of the classes, at the end of the calculation we will obtain the same path homotopy class, so we can dispense with the parentheses that norm we write to specify the order in which we are going to operate the classes of consecutive paths. For this reason on the left side of the equation we have omitted the parentheses when writing the finite product of classes in the statement of the theorem.

Comment: Having said that I do feel fishy about the first equality when I'm trying to  prove for the case  for n=k+1.

Comment: Well, in that first equality, since you already know the associative law, you are free to insert parentheses into that $k+1$-ary product as you please. That is one of the corollaries of the associative law for *any* binary operation.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. That's why I did it in the first place.